# Invoke javascript methods on a page

Tags: c#, javascript, python, scripting, browser

Is there a way using either C# or a scripting language, such as Python, to load up a website in the user's default webbrowser and continue to interact it via code (e.g. invoke existing Javascript methods)? When using WinForms, you can host a Webbrowser control and invoke scripts from there, but only IE is supported. Is there a way of doing the same thing in the user's default browser (not necessarily using WinForms)?

**Update:** The website is stored on the user's machine, not served from a third party server. It is a help page which works dynamically with my C# program. When the user interacts with my C# program, I want to be able to execute the Javascript methods on the website.

Comment: is default browser a requirement or just multiple browser support?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html). It can automate interaction with FireFox, IE, Chrome (with chromedriver) and Opera. It may not be suitable for your purposes due to the fact that it uses a fresh, stripped down profile, rather than the user's normal browser profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the HTTP request header you can determine the user-agent making the request.  Based upon that information you can write logic from the server side as to respond with a unique page per detected user-agent string.  Then you add any unique JavaScript you want as a static string to be executed by the user-agent application.

Comment: Since there is no HTTP there is no convention in place to detect the user-agent-string of the application.  You would have to ask the user what application they are using and then, on response, link them to the appropriate next page with the file scheme.